# e.values returns same value regardless of entered value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

My organization is setting up a queue system for product orders. The google script is supposed to send an automated email response confirming the order, but cannot pull the email address properly. 'var userEmail = e.values[x]' returns the same array value regardless of the value of x.

I have checked all relevant variables and ensured that the installable trigger is set up correctly. Google scripts pulls the array value automatically from an onFormSubmit trigger. The same code was implemented successfully by another organization who graciously donated the code for us to use, but something was lost in translation.

```
            var userEmail = e.values[3];
            MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
                        "unBound 3D Print #" + lastRow,
                        "Thanks for submitting your 3D print job. \n\nWe'll start " +
                        "working on it as soon as possible. You are currently " +
                        "number " +
                        (lastRow) + " in the queue. \n\nunBound Staff.",
                        {name:"unBound"});
```

By my understanding, e.values should return the associated answer to the appropriately numbered form question. In this case, e.values[0] should return the first question's answer, that being the user-submitted email address. Instead, any value entered returns the answer for the second question, that being the user's First Name, which is obviously not valid to send an email.

Edit:
Logs as requested. The following are the returns for e.values[x] at values 3, 2, and 1, respectively.

`D  {"values":["1/9/2019 15:49:29","email@address.com","Last","First","Ultimaker 3","File","Orange","0","0","https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NiOj10b002CeSMg6248f2e8yCNprhIN-",""],"namedValues":{"Status":[""],"Est. Weight Grams":["0"],"Print Time (Minutes)":["0"],"Upload File (.stl please)":["https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NiOj10b002CeSMg6248f2e8yCNprhIN-"],"Preferred Printer":["Ultimaker 3"],"Color":["Orange"],"First Name":["First"],"File Name":["File"],"Last Name":["Last"],"Timestamp":["1/9/2019 15:49:29"],"Email Address":["email@address.com"]},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":2,"rowEnd":2,"columnEnd":10},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":"299378"}`

`E  Invalid email: First
    at onFormSubmit(Code:53)`

`D  {"values":["1/9/2019 15:50:10","email@address.com","Last","First","Ultimaker 3","File","Orange","0","0","https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GeyYfqEqJNiEYUVqqDULZs0S7H6U6kUz",""],"namedValues":{"Status":[""],"Est. Weight Grams":["0"],"Print Time (Minutes)":["0"],"Upload File (.stl please)":["https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GeyYfqEqJNiEYUVqqDULZs0S7H6U6kUz"],"Preferred Printer":["Ultimaker 3"],"Color":["Orange"],"First Name":["First"],"File Name":["File"],"Last Name":["Last"],"Timestamp":["1/9/2019 15:50:10"],"Email Address":["email@address.com"]},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":2,"rowEnd":2,"columnEnd":10},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":"299378"}`

`E  Invalid email: First
    at onFormSubmit(Code:53)`

`D  {"values":["1/9/2019                        15:50:49","email@address.com","Last","First","Ultimaker 3","File","Orange","0","0","https://drive.google.com/open?id=10XLYK11UGuWtTppYDAyBeAU79jz5CRN8",""],"namedValues":{"Status":[""],"Est. Weight Grams":["0"],"Print Time (Minutes)":["0"],"Upload File (.stl please)":["https://drive.google.com/open?>id=10XLYK11UGuWtTppYDAyBeAU79jz5CRN8"],"Preferred Printer":["Ultimaker 3"],"Color":["Orange"],"First Name":["First"],"File Name":["File"],"Last Name":["Last"],"Timestamp":["1/9/2019 15:50:49"],"Email Address":["email@address.com"]},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":2,"rowEnd":2,"columnEnd":10},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":"299378"}`

`E  Invalid email: First
    at onFormSubmit(Code:53)`

Comment: `Instead, any value entered returns the answer for the second question,` I find that hard to believe. You're missing something else. Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` and post  couple of logs after couple of form submissions

Comment: Having some trouble with that. Added the code to the end of the email script, but no output is being printed to the console on the form, sheet, or script page.

Comment: Add it at the very top of your script. View>Stackdriver logging will have your logs

Comment: Posted as requested.

Comment: Email address is 1. ``console.log("email@values[1] is"+e.values[1])``

Comment: Noted, and correct. Not sure what that did, but it now operates correctly. Many thanks

Comment: Not possible. Log and see `console.log("email@values[1] is"+e.values[1])` Your log already states `"values":["1/9/2019 15:49:29","email@address.com","Last","First","Ultimaker 3","File","Orange","0","0","https` values is a array and has all the form values. Are you using  the name `userEmail` elsewhere in another script? **Edit:** Based on edit,`but it now operates correctly.`  ok

Comment: You had it right. I jumped the shark on that comment. If you post it as an answer I'll close out the question.

Comment: I can't post a answer as I still don't know the issue or what caused it or what you missed. However, feel free to post a answer yourself, if you're satisfied.